# MS HTA doesn't support CSS FlexBox and other modern features, could you suggest another way of converting HTML into Application?

Tags: web-apps, javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

All! I need to resolve the following conceptual question.
I used HTA for a dozen years, and I used to convert my HTAs to MS Windows exe files using old ExeScript software, which puts an HTA and all additional files into one exe file. If such an exe file is launched, it deploys "under the table" all contained files into MS Windows TEMP folder and runs HTA.
I liked it because I need to have access to local files to read them, to do some calculations and to write some output files.
I need to read MS Excel and plain text files that are created by other applications, so I used MS Windows ActiveX Objects like Scripting.FileSystemObject (to read and write local plain text files), shell.application (to show BrowseForFolder dialog), Excel.Application (to treat Excel) and some times WScript.Shell.
Such an approach worked well apart from I can't use new features of HTML 5 and CSS 3 because a number of that work for IE 11 HTML, but don't work for MS HTA in the same IE 11 mode.
HTA is slowly deceasing during a long time, so I'm looking for a modern realization of HTML application that can read and write local files beyond its sandbox as well as read Excel files. I prefer OpenSourse or free software. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

From what I read, the best next thing would be .Net MAUI. applications, using Razor for the GUI.

More there: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/403154/what-is-the-future-of-mshta-exe-since-internet-exp

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).